# php ctype_digit not telling whether the string is numeric

Tags: php

I have a script that i want to use to process user input from the clients. I have several checks but the very first one requires the submitted string to be numeric.

This is the code

```
<?php
$num = '09201x11222';

//Check whether the string is numeric
function test($str){
  return ctype_digit($str);
}

echo test($num);

echo '<br/><br/><br/>';

//Check if the length is exactly 10 characters
$len = strlen($num);
if($len < 10 || $len > 10){
  echo 'that number is wrong';
}
elseif($len == 10){
  echo 'that number is of required length';
}
echo '<br/><br/><br/>';
//Trim Leading Zero
$afterTrim = substr($num,1);

echo $afterTrim;

//Append countrycode 380 
echo '<br/><br/><br/>';

$countryCode = '380';
$afterAppend = $countryCode.$afterTrim;

echo $afterAppend;

?>
```

When the `$num` is correct, i get 1 on the screen but when its wrong i get nothing at all. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing `false` will result in a "void" print.  This because a `echo` needs to cast a boolean to a string representation.

As you can see from method signature

```
bool ctype_digit ( string $text )
```

this returns a boolean value that is converted by echo: if `true`, it will print `1`, otherwise it will print nothing.

From [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

Comment: @Mongodb you should not echo it directly but check for `true` or `false` and print an adeguate message.